# Variable de URL en PHP llega vacía

Tags: php

tengo un problema con una variable de url en php.
Consiste en que llamo la llave des un producto desde otra pagina (**donde el usuario NO a iniciado sesión**) y la paso por variable de url a una pagina de inicio de sesión.

Lo que quiero es que cuando el usuairo inicie sesión se **rediriga** a la pagina del producto con la **sesión ya iniciada**.
¡De antemano muchas gracias!

Aquí el codigo PHP que estoy usando:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    $extra = 'tienda.php';
    $var = "?emp=";
    $tienda = $_GET['emp'];

    $errors[] = login($usuario, $password);
    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra$var$tienda");
}
```

Comment: Necesitamos el código completo, tanto la zona donde generas esa variable como donde la usas. Es importante saber la localización de `session_start()` en ambos scripts.

Comment: Disculpa, veo que mandas la URL de retorno por `$_GET`, comparte el código en el que haces la redirección para ver el contenido que tiene.

Comment: session_start();
 $errors = array();

 if(!empty($_POST)){
  $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
  $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

  if(isNullLogin($usuario, $password)){
   $errors[] = "Debes llenar todos los campos";
   }
  $errors[] = login($usuario, $password);
 }
if (isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'tienda.php';
$var = "?emp=";
$tienda = $_GET['emp'];
    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra$var$tienda");
}

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega allí el código. Los comentarios tienen un límite de longitud y se pierde el formato.